# Simple protection against reflected XSS

Tags: web-browser, xss, browser-extensions

I was going through some CLIENT side defenses against reflected XSS e.g. XSS auditor(chrome), IE8 XSS Filters, Noscript. They use regular expression and other sophisticated techniques.

My question is- why don't we store what ever is going to server as parameters and if these parameters are reflected in HTML response then discard it or encoded it. Simple idea. I feel there may be false positives but not very convincing ones. Any input?

Answer (score 1):

this approach is already found in various frameworks and works (more or less) against basic attack-patterns.

another, more elegant way is to use [CSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy), but you have some requirements when using this approach (no inline js/styles etc)

the problem is, from defender-pov, an attacker might have other points), nasty stuff like encoding, nullbytes and different ways to mitigate protection. if it were just ASCII, the world would be ( a little more) perfect :)